# javascript function is not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox. If I checks it, it will select all results:
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectallcheckbox" onClick="toggle(this)" />
```

And Javascript:

```
function toggle(source = false) {
    if(!source)
    {
        var source = document.getElementById('selectallcheckbox');
    }
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('id[]');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    var id = checkboxes[i].id;
    var res = id.replace("checkbox", "tr");
    if(source.checked)
    {
        $('#' + res + '').addClass('selected');
    } else {
        $('#' + res + '').removeClass('selected');
    }
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to select all results if I click CTRL+A on my keyboard. Here is my JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    if (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 97) { // 'A' or 'a'
      e.preventDefault();
      toggle();
    }
  }
});
```

But this function is not works. How can I make ctrl + a to select all results

Comment: Is the event handler called? Do you get any errors? What have you done to debug the issue? You are in the best position to debug the code since you already have a running version.

Comment: If I change toggle();  to alert('Hi'); on my last code I got Hi. But I couldn't run toggle function

Comment: No I don't got any errors

Comment: So it doesn't even find the `toggle` function? You must get *some* error in the console.

Comment: share more html code if you have for checkboxes  ?

Comment: You must get an error if you are trying to run `toggle()` but it is not called. Or how are you verifying it's not called? Did you set a breakpoint? Or are you just assuming it's not called because whatever you want to happen doesn't happen?

Comment: Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/mu2yxpdt/
But It dont worked on jsfiddler. But its working on my pc

Comment: *"But It dont worked on jsfiddler. But its working on my pc"* can you elaborate?

Comment: I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle is not defined" in jsfiddle when I checks box. But on my WAMP I don't got this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toggle function requires an argument or nothing. When no argument is passed the argument itself can be got directly from the dom. In the html the toggle function get the this keyword. The element itself is passed. But if no argument is passed the argument is undefined and so it can be computed dynamically:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectallcheckbox" onClick="toggle(this)"/>
```

In the toggle function try to change from:

```
function toggle(source = false) {
   if(!source)
   {
      var source = document.getElementById('selectallcheckbox');
   }
   ...........
```

to:

```
   function toggle(source) {
        if (source === undefined) {
            source = document.getElementById('selectallcheckbox');
        }
```

and, finally, in your jQuery(document).keydown(function(e) { change to:

```
   jQuery(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            if (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 97) { // 'A' or 'a'
                e.preventDefault();

                // get the argument to the toggle function
                var eleObj = document.getElementById('selectallcheckbox');

                // toggle the checkbox status
                eleObj.checked = !eleObj.checked;

                // call the toggle function with the correct argument
                toggle(eleObj);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: But it don't unchecks checkbox if I press CTRL + A again :)

Comment: @AykhanAmiraslanli Now it will toogle

Comment: *"The toggle function requires an argument."* No it doesn't. That's what `function toggle(source = false) {` and `if(!source)` were there for.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry for what I wrote, I was attracted only from the way  to test for no arguments. I prefer a clear one. You are right in any case. Thanks.

Comment: Thought this still doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work. All you really changed (logic wise) was making the `if` condition *stricter* (`!source` => `source === undefined`). So that wouldn't make the function suddenly work. I assume that the OP was running the code in an environment that didn't support default parameters and hence parsing `function toggle(source = false) {` resulted in a syntax error. I don't believe the OP did not get any errors.

Comment: @FelixKling To be sure I tested the code in IE11 on win8.1: the console says: toggle is undefined

Comment: @FelixKling Now I am sure: there are limitations in browser support. [Default_parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    if (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 97) { // 'A' or 'a'
      e.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById("selectallcheckbox").click();
    }
  }
});
```